# How to open an URL in PRIVATE TAB (Incognito Browsing) from other android app

Tags: android-intent, incognito-mode

To open an URL in a browser from other android app is simple:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

In this way, however, the URL always opens in NORMAL TAB in android browser.

---

What can I do to open an URL in PRIVATE TAB or INCOGNITO MODE from other android app?

Answer (score -5):

Add flag= FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

```
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(yourUrl));
yourIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
context.startActivity(yourIntent);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY only removes the  **activity** from the history (so that the hardware back-button doens't remember it.